# Convert Int to UInt32 in Swift

Tags: swift, type-conversion

Im making a Tcp client and therefore using the `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` which is expecting an UInt32 for the second parameter.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do.:

```
func initNetwork(IP: String, Port: Int) {
    // relevant stuff

    //Convert Port:Int to UInt32 to make this shit work!

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, IP as NSString , Port , &readStream, &writeStream)

    // Irelevant stuff
}
```

I have been looking around for a solution for some time now, and i can't seem to find one!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
var x = UInt32(yourInt)
```

Comment: It's not casting. UInt provides an initializer that accepts Int.

Comment: Mind you, this will trigger a trap if the value is too large for a UInt32 and crash your program. Safer to use `UInt32(truncatingIfNeeded:)` as suggested below.

Comment: Annoying that this initializer does not show up in Xcode autocomplete. Options for `Uint32(bigEndian:` etc. but not for the function without any labels.

Answer (score 18):

[Nikos M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580013/9636) might overflow because Swift `Int`s are 64 bit now, and Swift will crash when the default UInt32 initializer overflows. If you want to avoid overflow, use [the `truncatingBitPattern` initializer](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-integer-overflow-issue-2970f3896f59).

If you're sure your data won't overflow, then you should use the default initializer because an overflow represents invalid data for your application. If you're sure your data will overflow, but you don't care about truncation (like if you're building hash values or something) then you probably want to truncate.

```
let myInt: Int = 576460752303423504
let myUInt32 = UInt32(truncatingBitPattern: myInt)
```

Comment: I disagree. This is silently changing the data. Triggering an explicit panic due to out-of-range port is better than pretending a different value was passed. Swift defaults to panic-on-overflow for a reason.

Comment: What is the best way to test, if the input value will trigger an overflow? `if myInt > Int(UInt32.max) { ... }`? `if  myInt == Int(UInt32(truncatingBitPattern: myInt)) { ... }`?

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple:

```
let int: Int = 40
let uint = UInt32(i)
```

in your case, just pass

```
UInt32(Port)
```

For a port is not a problem, but in other cases be sure to take care of overflow

*Side note*: in swift it's good practice to name variables using lower camel case, so with the first letter in lowercase

Answer (score 3):

Still more easier: (Wondering why they use the unsigned func)

```
var x = Int32(yourInt)
```

Comment: This is literally the exact same answer as the accepted answer, expect you use an Int32 instead of UInt32 which OP asks explicitly for